# perl slurp module issue

Tags: perl

```
root@bt:~/wepbuster-1.0_beta# ./wepbuster 
Can't locate File/Slurp.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.10 /usr/share/perl/5.10 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at ./wepbuster line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./wepbuster line 7.
root@bt:~/wepbuster-1.0_beta# cpan

cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v1.9402)
Enter 'h' for help.

cpan[1]> install Slurp
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.20)
Going to read '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
Database was generated on Wed, 10 Aug 2011 13:35:51 GMT
Slurp is up to date (0.4).

cpan[2]>
```

Hello,
how do I fix this little issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you want to do `install File::Slurp` not `install Slurp`, they are not the same thing.

On a general note, if you have a cpan module that you want to install even if cpan thinks it's up to date you can do `cpan[1]>force install File::Slurp` to force it to install again.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows with ActiveState Perl:

```
ppm install File-Slurp
```

worked for me. More details [here](http://code.activestate.com/ppm/File-Slurp/).